# How to run an AutoIT script on Windows Node using Chef?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, autoit

I'm attempting to install Applications (Adobe Reader, Access Database, etcetera) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Node by using Chef to download compiled AutoIT scripts onto the Node along with the corresponding installers - I've been using this approach because not all .exe files have silent installers and in my (limited) experience sometime a GUI installer gives the user more control over the application, allowing a user to set an application to "Check for updates manually", etcetera.

The compiled AutoIT scripts I've made work perfectly, but Chef for some reason will not run these .exe files.

I've tried the following approaches with Chef (placing both the application installers and the AutoIT Compiled Scripts in 'C:\To_Install'):

```
    powershell_script 'Run AutoIT installer with PowerShell' do 
         code <<-EOH

         C:\\To_Install\\#{fileName}

         EOH
     end
```

and

```
    execute 'Run AutoIT installer with CMD' do 
        command "C:\\To_Install\\#{fileName}"
    end
```

I am positive that all the applications I wish to install have been transferred to the node without error, and Chef is interacting with the node properly in all other ways (setting the clock, changing user permissions and settings, creating directories, etcetera).

Is there something I've overlooked? Does Chef run .exe files through some different process than a typicall user would?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error, instead Chef hangs on that powershell_script/execute instruction indefinitely - once there was at least some proof that the AutoIT installer had done something (I saw the program listed in the "remove programs" list, but the program did not run properly - instead it acted like it was half installed) which is what makes me think Chef must run some exe files in different way than a typical user.

Comment: How are you running chef-client? If it's via some way outside your normal GUI session then yes, that would probably not work.

Comment: I'm running chef client by bootstrapping the Windows Server 2012 Node and running the powershell_script/execute lines as part of the recipe I'm running on this node. Any pointers on why this doesn't work as it does in a normal GUI session?

Comment: You mean like `knife winrm bootstrap`?

Comment: Taking an example from https://learn.chef.io, I've been using this method: `knife bootstrap windows winrm 52.91.187.161 --winrm-user Administrator --winrm-password '7pXySo%!Cz' --node-name node1-windows --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_iis]'`

Comment: Yeah, so WinRM runs in a "headless session". Graphical tools generally won't work. I don't know of any good way around this. You'll need to fix your installers to have a true silent mode, or re-package them using MSI or Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying down from comments:

﻿Yeah, so WinRM runs in a "headless session". Graphical tools generally won't work. I don't know of any good way around this. You'll need to fix your installers to have a true silent mode, or re-package them using MSI or Nuget.